# Difference between node.js and chrome in v8

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

chrome version 49.0.2623.110 m

node v5.10.0

Here is my code:

```
var a = 0;

(function() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
    console.log(a);
} )();

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

chrome gives

```
1
1
2
```

node gives

```
0
0
2
```

Why does that happen?

Thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with V8, but the way global scope works in Node, and in browsers *(where the global scope is `window`)*. Try console logging `this`, and it should become clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a function is called without context (and you are running in non-strict mode) `this` defaults to the global object.

In a browser the top-level of your source code runs in the global context, so `this.a`, which is `window.a` is the same as the `var a` declared in the global context at the top. Assigning `this.a = 1` is the same as assigning `a = 1`.

In node.js each JavaScript file gets its own module context that is separate from the global context, so `var a = 0;` is not creating a global, and the global you created with `this.a = 1;` will be shadowed by the modules own `a`.

Comment: So in node console.log(b); goes up in the scope chain to get b, from module to global. Whereas in the browser the code is executed directly in the global scope.

Comment: In node the code is in the module scope whereas in the browser the code is the global scope. Thanks.

Comment: @EuInsumiPrunc Yes, `b` is the same in both because there is no `b` declared in the module to shadow the global.