# javascript - string object instance exhibits different behaviour in browser and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

This is not a real life scenario. I am trying to learn more about strings in js, and came across the following:

```
var name = new String('sann');

console.log('type of name=' ,typeof name); 
// returns object in nodejs but string in browser
console.log('name instanceof String' ,name instanceof String) 
// returns true in nodejs but false in browser
```

NodeJS output was in line with my expectation, I am puzzled by the browser output.
What is the reason for this difference in behaviour ?

Comment: I tested on both chrome and firexfox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are right.

The [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string-constructor) says (emphasis mine):

> The String constructor is the %String% intrinsic object and the
>   initial value of the String property of the global object. **When called
>   as a constructor it creates and initializes a new String object.** When
>   String is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it
>   performs a type conversion.

So `new String(value)` returns a String *object* rather that a primitive.

In a browser anyway, the global `window` object has a property called [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), whose setter automatically converts the supplied value into a string.

The same snippet, if wrapped into a function call, reports `name` to be of type `object`, as expected.

```js
(() =>
{
    var name = new String('sann');

    console.log('type of name', typeof name);
    console.log('name instanceof String', name instanceof String);
}
)();
```

In Node.js the global object does not have that property, and so `name` is treated as a plain value.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about window object in the browser, which does not exist in nodejs. You can also read this answer which explains your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36408348/3554534